# To replace or to update/insert?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a sixty thousand row table that I plan to put on BigQuery and want to keep updated. Should I replace the table whenever there's updates/inserts to be done? There could likely more than what the daily limits allow with standard SQL. Is there a gap where the data can't be queried during the replacement process? I'd prefer one second old data next second new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60,000 is small enough that you can replace entire table easily. And no matter how big the table is, the all metadata operations (including replace) are transactional, so there is no window of unavailability.